# Which Python value will result in null in the output of json.dumps()?

Tags: python, json

Everything I have searched for seems to be about handling `null` returns, when in this case I want to *output* an actual `null` without double quotes:

```
input_data['field1'] = "foo"
input_data['field2'] = "null"  # what to put here to get output below?
output_json = json.dumps(input_data)
```

This results in:

```
{"field1": "foo", "field2": "null"}
```

Here's what I *want* to get:

```
{"field1": "foo", "field2": null}
```

with *no* double quotes around the `null`. How do I do this?

Comment: Python's ``None`` translates to JSON's ``null``

Comment: This is a case where I missed that point, though TBH I did some searching.  Thanks.  If anyone wants to close this questing no prob but the re-word that was done might give it some value for the next poor slob..